# Count the number of functional digraphs with special restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algebraic-combinatorics

Given a set of $n$ nodes, how can I count the number of possible functional di-graphs whose biggest connected component contains k node? With a restriction that no node can have an edge point to itself. That is f(x)!= x.

More specifically, given n nodes, I would like to know how many different functional digraphs are there. The biggest connected component(s) in the group is of size k(meaning k nodes). The connected component in this questions is defined in a sense that all edges are replaced by the undirected version. So if a node A connects to a node B and another node C connect to node B, then two nodes are consider connected.

For example, if I am given 4 nodes, then there are $3^4=81$ different types of functional digraph in total. This is because everyone has (4−1)=3 choices(cannot choose itself). Now, considered the size of biggest connected components contained in the graph, there are two types of functional digraphs. A graph can either have two connected components of size 2 or one component of size 4.

There are three different functional di-graph with two size-2 components.

A↔B, C↔D
A↔C, B↔D
A↔D, C↔B
And 78 different functional digraph of size-3 components.

I've been thinking of this for like three days but has no idea how to crack it.

Observation: 
1. If you have (n+1) nodes in total, then you can have a group of (k+1) nodes by adding one node to the k-node group in the same question with n nodes. 
2. Reference may be two papers "The number of functional digraphs" and "The number of structures of finite relations". But I cannot understand them very well.
3. In general, there should be $(n-1)^n$ different functional digraphs in total.

Appreicate any directions!

Comment: [On the Number of Functional Digraphs -- Harary](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01342903) The pdf is easily found. Also look to Davies for an alternate approach. I'll confess I find the proofs quite a slog.